# What type of regex would I need to grab from data

Tags: javascript, json, regex, discord

What `regex` would I need to get `<t:1583277337:R>` to then replace it so it display the proper information (in this case: `3 Years ago`)

Why?
I'm trying to use it on Discord where Discord automatically converts `<t:1583277337:R>` to the corresponding data, but the API retrieved data (below) doesnt automatically convert on Discord Embeds

*Data*

```json
"bio": "     ,    ...\n\n\n<t:1583277337:R> <3"
```

Answer (score 3):

I won't give you the full solution, but here is the logic:

1. explicit regex match for an `<t:`, in sequence
2. digits of any amount
3. explicit regex match for `:R>`

You can use this regex in `String#replace`. The `replace` method can accept a callback as its second argument for a more powerful parsing of a match. In this case, you can process the string in the `replace` callback to whatever text you need

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#parameters

Answer (score 2):

Example with group name:

```
<t:(?<timestamp>\d*):R>
```

Try it here https://regex101.com/